# gcc doesn't create a binary file

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm trying to use a simple Windows API.

But my code doesn't create a binary file when I use 'MessageBoxA'. And it doesn't produce any error message.

If I don't use 'MessageBoxA', the code creates the binary file.

I use gcc version 6.3.0 on Windows 10. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello\n");

    MessageBoxA( 0, "hello", "aa", 0); // If I subtract this line, it works fine.

    return 0;
}
```

+) If there is `xxx.exe` file that exists in current directory and I command the following command, the command removes the `xxx.exe` file.

```
gcc myfile.c -o xxx.exe
```

- 2020-04-27) I attached a screenshot to show my compile result.
  [image: No error message screenshot]

Comment: If you don't get a binary, then the compiler must have output some kind of error message, which you should also include in your question.

Comment: Did you get any kind of message about `MessageBoxA` being missing when you tried to link your program?  If so, then you need to link with the library that provides it.

Comment: How do you compile your program? You must link against `user32`, probably with `-luser32` with gcc.

Comment: If you are editing in something like VS Code or other editor that saves in UTF-16, gcc will not be able to read it. (make sure you are saving to UTF-8 or ASCII)

Comment: If you really don't get an error message, is there any output at all? What if you intentionally introduce a syntax error (e.g. remove the semicolon after printf or something like that), do you get an error message then?

Comment: Sorry for all, I just found these comments. I'm not familiar with Stackoverflow, so 
I thought there was no answer.

Comment: @FelixG, I attached a screenshot after typing gcc compile command.
And I don't get any output. The strangest thing is that compiling this code will delete the existing binary file.

Comment: @TomKarzes
I tried several times, but I still don't get a error message. Please refer to my screenshot on the post.

Comment: @MOehm
I used the option that you mentioned, but the result is same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin
I already use the UTF-8 in VS Codium.

Comment: @heeamshin have you tried what happens if you compile a program with a syntax error? Because in that case you absolutely 100% guaranteed must get an error message, and if you still don't, then that problem needs to be addressed first.

Comment: Show the output of `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -O3 -o xxx.exe myfile.c` -- always compile with warnings enabled and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Post the text of the error message, (indented by 4-spaces) not a picture of the output. Compile from the *VS Developers Command Prompt* in the directory containing `myfile.c` so  you can select the text and press `[Enter]` to copy the text.

Comment: @FelixG `then the compiler must have output some kind of error message` - not necessarily, i have encountered  issues in the past where MinGW-g++ would just segfault/crash on windows, without outputting any error message prior to the crash.. pretty sure it happened more than once with MinGW-g++ version 3.4.2

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The command you mentioned returns the following error message: 
`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -03 -o library.exe library.c` ->
`gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-03'`

So I removed `-03` option, then it produced a binary file.
`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -o library.exe library.c`
And the resulting binary file makes message box as I intended.

And I used only `-std=c11` option, and it also produced a binary file.
`$ gcc -std=c11 library.c`

Comment: I guess there must be many version of C compiler in my computer. And MessageBoxA is not supported in old C compiler (like C99 or something)

Comment: `$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -o library.exe library.c` works, but don't produce any message. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -o library.exe library.c` don't work, but don't produce any message.

Comment: I solved this problem by installing mingw-w64 (I used mingw previously.)

Comment: Oh that should be `-`Oh`3` meaning `-O3` for (optimization level 3)

Comment: @hanshenrik that's interesting, i can't remember having a compiler actually crash on me without any output at all. I'm running linux though, so i don't use MinGW.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -O3 -o library.exe library.c` works (produce a binary file), but produces no message.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -O3 -o library.exe library.c` don't work, but produces no message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the solution for this issue as follows:

- Use `-std=c11` option when you use MinGW.
- Use another tool, like MinGW W64.

Thanks to @FelixG, @TomKarzes, @MOehm, @DavidC.Rankin, @hanshenrik